# If I've put the notes correctly in the first piano roll image, why does it not sound correct?

Tags: guitar, piano, chords, amplifiers, time-signatures

I used [this video](https://youtu.be/KrfUTgD6I7c) to find the notes of ghost riders in the sky.

Based on this image:

[image]

I created this in Fl Studio:

[image]

I used to resize all of them together, making them faster or slower.
But it doesn't sound like the music in the video!

Also, I recorded the beginning of the music and converted it to midi, and it sounded good.

[image]

If I've put the notes correctly in the first piano roll image, why does it not sound correct?

**Edit:** I think this time I've put the notes correctly:

[image]

And this sounds close to the second piano roll, but as you see, it has two more notes than the second piano roll, and it sounds bad.
So I know that 4 beats are a note, and in the second piano roll, it seems that there is a quartor note between the two "G3" and maybe there are some half notes; based on the guitar notes on the first image, how can I know if I should put a half note or a quartor note?

Comment: The guitar tab in the first image doesn't specify the note duration only the sequence of notes, so you need to write it yourself based on how the song sounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first image is completely different than what is played in the video. Just one example:

- The first note in the piano roll image is A6, but the first note played on guitar is the open E string, which is E2. That's why the second image sounds correct; it uses E2.

Comment: The low open E on guitar is E2, not E3. Agreed otherwise.

Comment: Some people told me that the translation of "0" in guitar to piano is "A," and "2" is "B," and "3" is "C." That's how I put the notes in the piano roll.

Comment: @Aaron I shifted all of the notes down, and now it begins with "E3," but it still doesn't sound correct.

Comment: @dsa Well, first, whoever told you 0 = A, etc., was wrong. But all of the notes are wrong, not just the first one. That was just an example. In order to translate the video to DAW, you'll have to learn a bit about how guitars work, which is a separate issue.

Comment: @Ramillies Oops. Thanks.

Comment: The low open E on guitar is E2, but FL studio uses a different numbering where C5 is middle C for some reason, so actually it would be marked E3 in the FL studio piano roll.  That is, assuming your guitar VSTi doesn't also displace by an octave.

Comment: @dsa As a pianist turned guitarist, converting tabs to piano roll/sheet music is actually "easy". The letters on the left side of the tab are the strings on which the notes are played. The numbers tell you to take this string and add the corrseponding amount of semitones (guitar cases/frets). For example, A)--3- means A+3 semitones, so C. E)0 means E. Using this, you should easily be able to translate tabs to score. What you did on the second piano roll is actually correct, modulo the number of notes. Later on, you will encounter bends and slides in tabs, but you should figure them out easily.

Comment: @Aaron, not entirely. Considering a guitar in standard tuning, that is correct for the second string.

Answer (score 3):

In the first image, the notes were not transcribed correctly. The guitar tab is correct, as you noticed by playing the song and converting it to MIDI, it is the conversion between guitar tab and score where the problem lies.

Guitars are commonly tuned, as seen in the beginning of the tab, in the EADGBE tuning.
Meaning, the 6th string is E2, the 5th is A above that, so A2, the 4th is D above the A so D3 and so on.
However, note that, as mentioned in the comments, this software uses a different octave numbering so 6th string is E3 and similarly every other note's octave is increased by 1: E3, A3, D4, G4, B4, E5.

Once you know what note the string is tuned to, every fret will add one half step to the note that would be played by plucking the free string, so the A (5th) string on fret 2 is A->A#->B so a B2. 3rd fret is A->A#->B->C so a C3.

This same progression you also mentioned is only for the 5th string though, and does not work on other strings, since every string plays a different note when played free. For example, E (6th) string on 3rd fret is E->F->F#->G so G2, or G3 for FL studio as seen in the recording to MIDI.